# Showing non-ascii characters in URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to make a page that will show Arabic/Hebrew in the URL.
for example: **www.mydomain.co.ar/אבא.php**

Problem is, when i upload the page to the Apache server and try to browse to that
page either with "www.mydomain.co.ar/אבא.php" or the percent encoding way
"www.mydomain.co.ar%D7%90%D7%91%D7%90.php" i get a 404.

Then i list the directory and apache sees **àáà.php**.
I know there is a way to show up non ASCII in url, wikipedia is doing it for ages.

My thoughts are maybe .htaccess rewrite? if so how can i accomplish that?

Comment: I just created a file with that name and accessed it fine on localhost.

Comment: how? i have two shared servers and on both of them i have this problem. could it because i use FileZilla to transfer the files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have to tell apache that the file system is encoded in UTF-8 (or whatever). Maybe starting apache with an UTF-8 locale active (`LC_CTYPE=ar.utf8` or similar) helps there.

Wikipedia parses the URLs in the PHP software (and then asks the database about the right article), so this does not necessarily say how Apache does this.

Comment: wow i don't think my shared hosting allows changing apache configurations. what a total blow :(

Comment: @Tom If it's a service then get the support to do what you're paying them to :-)